# Orientability and Spin of projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$, $\mathbb{CP}^n$, $\mathbb{HP}^n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

1. What are the orientability of the real projective space
   $\mathbb{RP}^n$, the complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^n$ and the quaternionic projective space $\mathbb{HP}^n$, for any $n$?
2. Are the $\mathbb{RP}^n$, $\mathbb{CP}^n$ and $\mathbb{HP}^n$ spin-manifold or not, for any $n$?

p.s. What is known: I know $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is non-orientable for even $n$ and orientable for odd $n$. I know orientable manifolds for $n \leq 3$ all are spin manifold. I know $\mathbb{CP}^4$ is orientable but not spin manifold.

Partial answers are welcome.

Comment: $w_1(\Bbb{RP}^n) = 0$ iff $n$ is odd. $w_1$ of the others is zero. $w_2(\Bbb{RP}^n) = 0$ iff $n$ is 1 or 2 mod 4. $w_2(\Bbb{CP}^n))$ is zero iff $n$ is odd. $w_2(\Bbb{HP}^n)$ is automatically zero for cohomological reasons. I'm sure the first two calculations are in Milnor-Stasheff.

Comment: @Mike Miller, Thanks! That is really a nice comment. What don't you write up as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the canonical isomorphism $H_k(\Bbb{RP}^n;\Bbb Z/2) = \Bbb Z/2$, it is well-known (see e.g. Milnor and Stasheff) that $w_k(\Bbb{RP}^n) = \binom{n+1}{k} \mod 2$. In particular, $w_1(\Bbb{RP}^n) = n+1$ and thus is zero iff $n$ is odd, and $w_2(\Bbb{RP}^n) = n(n+1)/2 \pmod 2$ for $n \geq 2$, and thus is zero iff $n = 0, 1$, or $n>2$ and $n$ is equal to $n=0$ or $3$ mod $4$.

One has identical results for $\Bbb{CP}^n$ and its Chern classes (which reduce mod 2 to its even Steifel-Whitney classes), and so $w_2(\Bbb{CP}^n)$ is zero iff $n$ is odd, and of course its $w_1$ is always zero as it has trivial first cohomology.

$\Bbb{HP}^n$ has trivial first and second cohomology so its $w_1$ and $w_2$ are automatically zero (and satisfies the same formula above for $w_{4k}$.)

A manifold is orientable iff $w_1(M) = 0$, and is spin iff both $w_1$ and $w_2$ are zero. So $\Bbb{RP}^n$ is orientable for odd $n$, and spin for $n = 4k+3$; $\Bbb{CP}^n$ is always orientable and spin when $n$ is odd; and $\Bbb{HP}^n$ is always spin.

Comment: you wrote "$w_2(\Bbb{RP}^n) = (n+1)(n+2)/2$, and thus is zero iff $n$ is 2 or 3 mod 4." However, I think
$$
w(\Bbb{RP}^2)=1+a+a^2,
$$
where $w_0(\Bbb{RP}^2)=1$ and $w_1(\Bbb{RP}^2)$ and $w_2(\Bbb{RP}^2)$ are both non-zeros. $\Bbb{RP}^2$ is a Pin$^-$ manifold, non-oriented and non-spin, isn't it?

Comment: Something is horribly wrong.

Comment: Please modify it to appropriate, otherwise, it cannot be the accepted correct answer. Orz...

Comment: If $w_k(\Bbb{RP}^n) = \binom{n+1}{k} \mod 2$. Isn't that $w_2(\Bbb{RP}^n) = (n+1)(n)/2$? So what you had was incorrect? When $n=1,3,4$, $w_2(\Bbb{RP}^n)=0$ only $n=1,3,4$ but $w_2(\Bbb{RP}^2)=1$?

Comment: I will mark it as an accepted answer again - once this issue/mistake is taken care. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, just to make sure the SW class $w$ of $w(\mathbb{HP}^n) = (1+u)^{n+1}$ is given by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_projective_space#Characteristic_classes, it does not seem to me that $w_1(\mathbb{HP}^n)=w_2(\mathbb{HP}^n)=0$ always? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @wonderich Yeah, my apologies for the first combinatorics mistake. What you write is correct. I've edited to fix it (though keep in mind you are also able to edit answers; if you find other mistakes like this I encourage you to do so.) While $\binom{n+1}{2} = n(n+1)/2$ for $n > 2$, there are some special low-dimensional cases for which that formula is not true; $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ as opposed to $6$ (and this gives $w_2(\Bbb{RP}^2) = 1$), and while $\binom{2}{2} = 1$, $H^2(S^1;\Bbb Z/2) = 0$, so there's nowhere for $w_2(\Bbb{RP}^1)$ to live; it is also zero.

Comment: @wonderich I haven't checked the wikipedia link, but I think the formula is intended differently: $u$ is the generator of $H^4(\Bbb{HP}^n;\Bbb Z)$, which generates the cohomology ring. We must have $w_k(\Bbb{HP}^n) = 0$ unless $k = 0$ mod $4$, as $H^k(\Bbb{HP}^n) = 0$ unless $k = 0$ mod $4$. (Here this is true for any $n$.) The formula then means to say that $w_{4k}(\Bbb{HP}^n) = \binom{n+1}{k} u^k \in H^{4k}(\Bbb{HP}^n;\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Thanks, I find this in p.6 (p.689) of http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/szczarba.pdf

Comment: About this again yours seems wrong "$w_2(\Bbb{RP}^n) = n(n+1)/2 \pmod 2$ for $n > 2$, and thus is zero iff $n = 0, 1, 2$, or $n>2$ and is equal to $0$ or $3$ mod $4$." I think you meant "thus is zero iff $n = 0, 1$, or $n>2$ and is equal to $0$ or $3$ mod $4$."

Comment: When $n=2$, it is nonzero!?

Comment: @wonderich Your comment is correct (my mistake on adding $n=2$ to the list of cases it is zero). Thank you for editing to fix this; you do not need to comment if you find such a mistake.